# How to "secure" store information in cookies?

Tags: php, cookies

Source is here http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice

Please advice improvements (changes for the method). Here I want to store only username in cookie so that user do not need to enter username. Store in a way that hacker can not know username from stolen cookie (if that is possible)

If user check Remember me and successfully login

1) create something depending on username. For example $username_for_cookie = MD5($username).$salt;+may be something else. Record $username_for_cookie in mysql

2) Create identifier. Simple random value. Record the indetifier in mysql

3) Create token. Also simple random value and also record in mysql.

4) Create cookie putting all the above values together $username_for_cookie . $identifier .$token

Cookie name may be also random value or something like _ekglasjd

User revisit website

1) check if cookie exists

2) if cookie exists separate $username_for_cookie . $identifier .$token to get 3 separated values

3) search in mysql if $username_for_cookie value exists. If does not exist, login form to enter username and password. If exists compare if $identifier and $token are the same as in mysql

Is such method "safe"? What need to improve?

Comment: Don't store secure data on the client, keep it on the server.  All the cookie really needs is to persist the session id.  Probably don't want to reinvent the wheel on this one.

Comment: @ficuscr Thats not a good statement for this case. All that the cookie would be storing is a one time token to enable persistent login.

Comment: @datasage, yeah, reading it again you are correct.  I typically use two cookies when doing something like this, a longer living 'tracking' cookie, and the normal 'logged user' session cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve this by doing the following.

1. Only use https.
2. Reset the token after its been used.
3. Token has to be used within a certain window before it will expire and the user needs to login again.
4. Ensure the token is sufficiently random that it cannot be reproduced. Should not be build with user data.